# bcdedit - how to tell which drive the identifier belongs to?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bcdedit

When using `bcdedit /enum firmware`, it lists all the boot entries, but I have 2 drives and identical entries for both of them and I can't tell which drive is which.

How to know?

There is the device name (`partition=\DeviceHarddiskvolume2`), but how do I know which is which?

Comment: You use DiskPart to identify which disk is volume2

Comment: Ty, how can I `list volume` on specific disk and not all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign a drive letter to the partition, bcdedit will automatically display that (instead of NT paths).

For example, running `mountvol S: /s` will (temporarily) assign the letter `S:` to the *currently used* EFI System Partition, at which point bcdedit will start showing `partition=S:` for the EFI boot entry. (The `/d` option removes the assignment.)

Comment: yep, it shows the letter instead, thank you. didn't try to unassign yet though (after a restart it also unassign).